# "Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable" issue?

Tags: c#

I'm getting a *Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable* with Resharper and I'm trying to find out if it's really an issue or not. This is my method:

```
public IEnumerable<Contact> GetContacts(IContactManager contactManager, string query)
{
    IEnumerable<Contact> contacts = contactManager.GetContacts(query);
    if (contacts.Any()) return contacts; // Get the warning on this line
    // Do some other stuff
    return new[] {
        new Contact { Name = "Example" }
    }
}
```

Should be obvious, but I'm doing a search for `Contact` and if the search returns no results I'm returning an array of default values. The consumer should just receive a list which can be enumerated, not modified.

Where is the "multiple enumeration" here? And if there is indeed one, is this not the best type to use in the situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The multiple enumeration potential is you calling `Any`, which will cause the first enumeration, and then a *potential* second enumeration by the caller of that method.

In this instance, I'd guess it is mostly guaranteed that two enumerations will occur at least.

The warning exists because an `IEnumerable` can disguise something expensive such as a database call (most likely an `IQueryable`), and as `IEnumerable` doesn't have caching as part of it's contract, it will re-enumerate the source fresh. This can lead to performance issues later on (we have been stung by this a surprising amount and we don't even use `IQueryable`, ours was on domain model traversal).

That said, it is still only a warning, and if you are aware of the potential expense of calling an enumerable over potentially slow source multiple times then you can suppress it.

The standard answer to caching the results is `ToList` or `ToArray`.

<sub>Although I do remember making an `IRepeatable` version of `IEnumerable` once that internally cached as it went along. That was lost in the depths of my gratuitous code library :-)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

`Enumerable.Any` executes the query to check whether or not the sequnce contains elements. You could use [`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to provide a different default value if there are no elements:

```
public IEnumerable<Contact> GetContacts(IContactManager contactManager, string query)
{
    IEnumerable<Contact> contacts = contactManager.GetContacts(query)
        .DefaultIfEmpty(new Contact { Name = "Example" });
    return contacts;
}
```

Note that this overload is not supported in LINQ-To-SQL.

Comment: I guess this will not get rid of the warning. You missed `//Do some other stuff` part, presumably that will enumerate the collection and result in waring!.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: i assume that _"do some other stuff"_ is just the part where he provides the default/fallback array that should be returned if the query does not yield a result. However, it might be the best option to ignore this warning since OP's approach should be fine.

Comment: Sorry, @TimSchmelter is correct. `// Do some other stuff` is just populating the fallback array